# "Parrot issue": remote ssh server returns my own commands

Tags: c#, ssh

My app uses C# library [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) for connection with a remote Ubuntu server.
 
There is the code which reads and writes into the stream of client-sever data:

```
ShellStream mainStream = client.CreateShellStream("xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);//it represents the main stream

//send any data to sever
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(mainStream);//wrapper for main stream
await  writer.WriteLineAsync(command);
await  writer.FlushAsync();//flush data from main stream (i.e. send to server)

//get data from server (this is the timer's callback):
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mainStream);//another wrapper for reading
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] buffer = new char[128];
int i = 0;
    while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
        if ((i = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))!= 0)
        {
        sb.Append(buffer, 0, i);                  
        }                   
}
return sb.ToString();
```

It works good, but sometimes it returns my inputted commands for server. I could think that my issue is hidden in my code, but debugging window shows that data comes from mainStream, i.e. from server.

Is it possible my sended command was returned  back? Or is my problem in wrong code?

**Edit**: I called 'history' command on my server, it returns all earlier sended commands. After the issue is occured the server does **not** receive any command from client. However the connection is set still, any error are absent.
What could it be?